# Is there a method in java that returns member variables of a class

Tags: java

I have a requirement to check if the member variables of a class are there in a list or not. For this, I need to get all the variables of a class dynamically (if possible as a list). Is there a method for that in java?

Thanks,
KD

Comment: The values of the variables or the variable/field names?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think he is referring to the latter (most likely looking for `Class#getFields()`)

Comment: Btw, docs for [`Class#getFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields())

Comment: @MadProgrammer Field Names.

Comment: No problem, but I'll also give @JoshM props for mentioning the method first.

Answer (score 2):

This is the concept of [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).  You should be able to do something like the following (untested) code snippet:

```
/**
 * @return {@code true} if all of the values of the fields in {@code obj} are
 * contained in the set of {@code values}; {@code false} otherwise.
 */ 
public boolean containsAllValues(HashSet<Object> values, MyClass obj) {
  Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getFields();

  for (Field field : fields) {
    Object fieldValue = field.get(obj);
    if (values.contains(fieldValue)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may get all of the field names (and their values) by calling `Class#getFields()`

Example: Consider the class below

```
public class Test{
    public int x, y, z;
}
```

`Test.class.getFields()` will return the fields `x`,`y`,`z`, in which you could get their name through `Field#getName()` and get their value by calling the appropriate `get` method. In the `Test` class above, you could do something like this:

```
Test instance = new Test();
instance.x = 50;
int xValue = Test.class.getField("x").getInt(instance);
```

The value of `xValue` would be 50.

For a better demonstration of how it works, please see [this](http://ideone.com/pJSruu).

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about **reflection**.

Have a look at Class.getFields():

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

See also:

http://forgetfulprogrammer.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/java-reflection-class-getfields-and-class-getdeclaredfields/

There are quite a lot of fishhooks with reflection. Property-based access -- bean properties, of the form getX()/setX() or isX()/setX() -- may be a little better in helping you avoid unstable implementation internal of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getFields()` method, that will return a `Field` array: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()

And then the `getName()` method for each element in the `Field[]` to get the name: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName().

Answer (score 0):

Most answers recommend [Class.getFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) but as the JavaDoc states, it will only return the public fields:

> Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting all the
>   accessible public fields of the class or interface represented by this
>   Class object.

I rarely make my class fields public and rather make them private with getters and setters. To  get the list of all fields (including private, protected and package private) you need to use  [Class.getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29):

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared
>   by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This
>   includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   fields, but excludes inherited fields.

Note that unlike Class.getFields(), Class.getDeclaredFields() will not returned the inherited fields. To get those you need to loop through the class hierarchy (loop over Class.getSuperclass() until you reach Object.class). Private fields names could be repeated in parent classes.